# how to use regex or split in python2.7

Tags: python, regex, buffer

this is a file content that has more than 6000 lines of such similar lines:

```
0000000: 01010000 01001011 00000011 00000100 00010100 00000011  PK....  
0000006: 00000000 00000000 00001000 00000000 01000000 10001101  ....@.  
000000c: 00101001 01000110 10011111 00101100 00000001 11100100  )F.,..  
0000012: 01111100 00101011 00000000 00000000 10111110 11010111  |+....  
0000018: 00000010 00000000 00001101 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......  
000001e: 01110000 01100001 01101110 01100100 01100001 01011111  panda_  
0000024: 01100010 01101001 01101110 00101110 01110100 01111000  bin.tx  
000002a: 01110100 10101100 10011010 01001001 10101110 10011011  t..I..  
0000030: 01010000 00010000 01000101 11100111 01011001 10000101  P.E.Y.
```

and i need is to pull out portion of contents(column 2 to 7 only) from every line till eof and place it inside another file using python.

*I **first tried** to just copy and paste line after line till eof,.*

```
import StringIO 

infile = "input.txt"
outfile = open("dump.txt", "w")

with open(infile, 'r') as contents:
    line_infile = contents.readline()
    while line_infile:
        outfile.write(line_infile)
        line_infile = contents.readline()
outfile.close()
```

***It worked.***

*As a second step **i then added 're' inside**.. This is where im unable to do it.
this is the code i have written:*

```
import StringIO 
import re

infile = "input.txt"
outfile = open("dump.txt", "w")
match = re.compile(ur': (.*?)  ')

with open(infile, 'r') as contents:
    line_infile = contents.readline()
    while line_infile:
        outfile.write(re.findall(match, line_infile))
        line_infile = contents.readline()
outfile.close()
```

which gives error

```
outfile.write(re.findall(match, line_infile))
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

when tried it with re.copy_reg instead of re.findall

```
outfile.write(re.copy_reg(match, line_infile))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

im a beginner to programming and python. from what i have learnt so far, i have to make use of regex for matching strings, and use buffer to read large amount of datas. im using regular expression `': (.*?)  '` to select the contents btw 2 matching characters, `": "`(a ':' and a Space) and `"  "`('Space' and 'Space' ).

**Question:**

- how to copy those contents that matches the regex expression and place
  it inside another file.
- should i make use of buffer,.(i dont know how to make use of buffer.
  couldn't find much(examples or tutorials) about using buffer with
  readline() and write()module.)

Comment: @ahosan saw your output,.. thats how i wanted exactly to look like,... thanks for the expression,.. but what else is missing in my code to achieve that output.
please do not delete your answer,.. I felt it usefull regarding regex expression

Comment: `readline()` is pretty fast and memory saving, so you dont need `StringIO` here. `buffer` and `regex` are a little bit python advance and I don't thing they are suitable for beginner. You should learn the basic about string method, file I/O, list, tuple, dict ... first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if everything you need is in column 2 to 7 only, you can split the line and then take only the elements that you need.

```
infile = "input.txt"
outfile = open("dump.txt", "w")

with open(infile, 'r') as contents:
    for line in contents:
        line_infile = line.split(' ')[1:7]
        outfile.write(' '.join(line_infile) + '\n')

outfile.close()
```

Comment: your code worked for just one line,..
so i added my while loop to it,.. then it worked as expected. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:** use regex `[^\:]+:([\d\s]+\s\s).*`. it gives you only 2-7 column for each line. and explode this by new line..

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'[^\:]+:([\d\s]+\s\s).*', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"0000000: 01010000 01001011 00000011 00000100 00010100 00000011 PK.... \n0000006: 00000000 00000000 00001000 00000000 01000000 10001101 ....@. \n000000c: 00101001 01000110 10011111 00101100 00000001 11100100 )F.,.. \n0000012: 01111100 00101011 00000000 00000000 10111110 11010111 |+.... \n0000018: 00000010 00000000 00001101 00000000 00000000 00000000 ...... \n000001e: 01110000 01100001 01101110 01100100 01100001 01011111 panda_ \n0000024: 01100010 01101001 01101110 00101110 01110100 01111000 bin.tx \n000002a: 01110100 10101100 10011010 01001001 10101110 10011011 t..I.. \n0000030: 01010000 00010000 01000101 11100111 01011001 10000101 P.E.Y. "
subst = u"\1\n"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

**[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJ0zM2/2)**

**Python update..**  now it may works

```
import StringIO 
import re

infile = "input.txt"
outfile = open("dump.txt", "w")
p = re.compile(ur'[^\:]+:([\d\s]+\s\s).*', re.MULTILINE)
subst = u"\1\n"
with open(infile, 'r') as contents:
    line_infile = contents.readline()
    while line_infile:
        outfile.write(re.sub(p, subst, line_infile))
        line_infile = contents.readline()
outfile.close()
```

Comment: saw your output,.. thats how i wanted exactly to look like,... thanks for the expression,.. but what else is missing in my code to achieve that output.

Comment: I don't know python. so, i can't better help for your code. i try to help by regex. and i get python code from https://www.regex101.com/ this site. please want help another person...

Comment: ,.. sorry, that didn't work,.. the output file(dump.txt) had a repeated "$1" with a newline(\n) through out the file.
dragon2fly's method worked for me. thanks a lot for the regex expression.

Comment: Then, `subst = u"$1\n"` change to `subst = u"\1\n"`  and if add double newlin, then change to `subst = u"\1"`

Comment: tried both,.. the file now has a(some strange) character instead of `$1` (used gedit to open the file). in vim and nano that character was `^A`.
tried by removing the `\n` character, only the line gets removed, but the strange character still stays through out the file.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response. actually, i don't know python. and i have no any ide for test code. so, i can't help properly. i have tried to see your code example. i am not exact right...

Comment: @AhosanKarimAsik, @arvindh if you want to use regex to do this job, just find the thing you need instead of replacement.

`outfile.write(re.findall('(?<=: )[\d\s]*(?=  )',line_infile)[0] + '\n')` will do the job well.

Comment: @dragon2fly thanks, that worked too.
thanks both of u